# How to reduce boiler and repeatitive code when writing test cases

Tags: angular6, angular-test

I am writing a lot of boiler and duplicate code in each `describe` section of my `app-component.spec.ts`. Is there a way to reduce it? Another problem is that whenever I write a new `component`, I have to explicitly add reference of the new `component` in each `describe`. For eg.

```
    describe('AppComponent Test suite', () => {

      let component: AppComponent;
      let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;

      beforeEach((() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          declarations: [
            AppComponent,
    ... //29 components need to be referrred her
          ],
          imports: [
            AppRoutingModule,
            QuillModule,
            BrowserModule,
            HttpClientModule,
            MatProgressBarModule,
            BrowserAnimationsModule,

           HttpClientXsrfModule.withOptions({cookieName: 'CJCsrfCookie', headerName: 'CJCsrfHeader'}),
            ReactiveFormsModule
          ],
          providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'},
    ...//14 services need to be added here
        }).compileComponents();
      }));

      beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
      });

      fit('should create the app', (async() => {

        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
      }));
...
});
```

If I write another `describe`, I'll have to write all the `imports` and `declarations` again. Can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems it is quite easy to do it unless I am mistaken!

I just import the `AppModule`. For any `providers` I want to provide an alternate of, I just mention that explicitly.

eg.

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule],
      providers: [
        {provide: UserManagementService, useClass: MockUserManagementService}, //mock user management service
        ],
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

The above replaces

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [//23 components. These in new implementation come from AppModule
      ],
      imports: [AppModule],
      providers: [//14 services. They also some now from AppModule,
        {provide: UserManagementService, useClass: MockUserManagementService}, //mock user management service
        {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'}],
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```